# Imported GPS data does not overlap with map

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, geocoding

I am working on QGIS and I geocoded 2 addresses of a city in Germany and tried to input the text-file as a layer. It worked, but the 2 points must be in the map of the city and if I zoom to the layer-file they are far away. I tried EPSG 3857 (like the other layers) and ESPG 4326. With the last one it was much nearer, but still not in the city-map. On-the-fly-projection is activated.

How can I get the points into the right place in my map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Marienplatz 26, 88214 Ravensburg, Germany**

Response:

lat:47.7803930
lng:9.6139970

Quality = **ROOFTOP** (The best response from Google Geocoder)

```
<GeocodeResponse><status>OK</status><result><type>street_address</type><formatted_address>Marienplatz 26, 88214 Ravensburg, Germany</formatted_address><address_component><long_name>26</long_name><short_name>26</short_name><type>street_number</type></address_component><address_component><long_name>Marienplatz</long_name><short_name>Marienplatz</short_name><type>route</type></address_component><address_component><long_name>Ravensburg</long_name><short_name>Ravensburg</short_name><type>locality</type><type>political</type></address_component><address_component><long_name>Ravensburg</long_name><short_name>Ravensburg</short_name><type>administrative_area_level_3</type><type>political</type></address_component><address_component><long_name>Tübingen</long_name><short_name>TÜ</short_name><type>administrative_area_level_2</type><type>political</type></address_component><address_component><long_name>Baden-Wurttemberg</long_name><short_name>BW</short_name><type>administrative_area_level_1</type><type>political</type></address_component><address_component><long_name>Germany</long_name><short_name>DE</short_name><type>country</type><type>political</type></address_component><address_component><long_name>88214</long_name><short_name>88214</short_name><type>postal_code</type></address_component><geometry><location><lat>47.7817420</lat><lng>9.6139970</lng></location><location_type>ROOFTOP</location_type><viewport><southwest><lat>47.7803930</lat><lng>9.6126480</lng></southwest><northeast><lat>47.7830910</lat><lng>9.6153460</lng></northeast></viewport></geometry></result></GeocodeResponse>
```

Source:

XML:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Marienplatz+26+Ravensburg+Germany&sensor=false

available as JSON:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Marienplatz+26+Ravensburg+Germany&sensor=false

**Visual on a Map**
http://maps.google.de/maps?q=47.7803930,+9.6139970&hl=de&sll=51.151786,10.415039&sspn=8.58956,23.269043&t=m&z=16